# NoSuchMethodError exception from Java MapReduce pipeline POST /mapreduce/workerCallback?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-storage, nosuchmethod

Do you know of a workaround for this uncaught exception from the Java mapreduce pipeline on Google App Engine?

Is it simply a failure in GcsServiceFactory that created GCS_SERVICE in this line?
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/appengine/tools/mapreduce/inputs/GoogleCloudStorageLineInputReader.java?r=462#80

Any ideas on how to fix?

We are seeing this frequently:

```
 2013-09-24 18:18:17.819 Uncaught exception from servlet
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(Lcom/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsFilename;JI)Ljava/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel;
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.inputs.GoogleCloudStorageLineInputReader.beginSlice(GoogleCloudStorageLineInputReader.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.impl.WorkerShardTask.run(WorkerShardTask.java:84)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.impl.shardedjob.ShardedJobRunner.runTask(ShardedJobRunner.java:265)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.impl.shardedjob.ShardedJobServiceImpl.handleWorkerRequest(ShardedJobServiceImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.impl.handlers.MapReduceServletImpl.doPost(MapReduceServletImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.MapReduceServlet.doPost(MapReduceServlet.java:57)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see any of the below possible reasons :

1. You did not include all the jars in classpath, they might have
   interdependent classes.
2. You jar is an old version which is not
   having that method.
3. Some dependent jar is missing which not allowing the class constructor to initialize the class object.

Comment: It was a combo of 2 & 3. We had a dependent jar that was referencing another dependent jar that had changed. thanks.